# Stuck in infinite loop C# (while loop)

Tags: c#, text, while-loop, do-while

Hello guys i am new to programming and just learned some basics so i am stuck in this ifinite loop if someone can help me how to solve this

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game guess the word");
        Console.WriteLine("First word will be:");
        Console.Write("City located in Europe in EX Yugoslavia is:");
        string userWordInput = Console.ReadLine();
        int i = 0;
        do
        {

            for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong");
            }

        } while (userWordInput!="Sarajevo");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `userWordInput` does not change in your loop. Probably you are missing a `userWordInput = Console.ReadLine();` in the loop

Comment: Hey man thank you very much it worked you are a legend

Comment: You also probably want to change the do...while loop to a regular while loop becasue you will always get a message saying that the answewr is wrong on the 1st attepmpt

Comment: You should change the `do` loop to `while (userWordInput != "Sarajevo" && i < 5) { Console.Write("That's incorrect, please try again: "); userWordInput = Console.ReadLine(); i++; }`

Comment: Thank you guys i figured something and added additional score point and decrementing of score point if answer is wrong

Comment: @Dome; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game guess the word");
Console.WriteLine("First word will be:");
Console.Write("City located in Europe in EX Yugoslavia is:");
string userWordInput = Console.ReadLine();
int i = 0;
do
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your input is wrong");
    }
} while (Console.ReadLine() != "Sarajevo");
```